# In Python, Need an Efficient way to map kdtree indexes to the values

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, scikit-learn, kdtree

I am using kdtree from scikit-learn with a very large data set.

I can get kdtree to do the query in a somewhat reasonable time (20 minutes on my machine) but I can't map the indexes to the values they represent in any time less than 1 hour (I stop waiting after 1 hour).

I load up 2 csv files (train.csv has 29M records, test.csv has 8M records).  I am interested in 3 keys.  'x','y' which are floats and 'placeid' which is a string.

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KDTree
import pandas as pd

train = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
test = pd.read.csv("test.csv")

tree = KDTree(train[['x','y']])
_, indexes = tree.query(test[['x','y']],k=30)

# takes 20 minutes to get here.  Here is the code that takes more than an hour

result = [[train.iloc[idx].place_id for idx in idx_set] for idx_set in indexes]
```

Is there a faster way to do this?  My goal here is to map all the indexes that get returned from KDTree to the place_ids.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can give it a try, since you don't want distance from `query`:

```
indexes = tree.query(test[['x','y']],k=30,return_distance=False,dualtree=True,sort_results=False)
```

This might reduce some computation time for the first part.
For the second part , I am thinking about flatten or `reshape` indexes and slice `place_id` instead of dual loops. Can you provide the format of `result`? Is it just a simple list?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  As far as result, I'm trying to get an answer in terms of place_ids.  kdtree.query returns a list of indexes.  My problem is mapping the indexes back to the pandas dataframe column value for that index.  KDTree is returning a list of lists:  [[1,2,3,...],[5,6,7,8,...], ...].  I want to convert this to a list of strings.  [['place123','place256',...],['place115','place2445', ..], ..].  In my example, there are 30 elements in each element-list and a total of 8M of these element-lists in the list of lists.

Comment: I see. You can try `ix` instead of `iloc`. Although `iloc` and `loc` are explicit and intuitive, `ix` are usually faster than `iloc`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I'll test it out.  :-)